# on linux: lyx looses changes in preferences after restarting (screen font, color etc)

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I am on linux/ ubuntu 14.04 and my user directory can be found in `/.lyx`. I was able to paste a color theme into `/.lyx/preferences` but when I try to make changes to the preferences within lyx, the changes are lost when I restart the program.

I checked the permissions of the `preferences`-file as well as the folder and found them to be `-rw-rw-rw-` so lyx should be able to alter them. What can I do?

---

### My `preferences`

```
# LyX 2.0.8.1 generated this file. If you want to make your own
# modifications you should do them from inside LyX and save.

Format 1

\bind_file "emacs"

#
# MISC SECTION ######################################
#

\serverpipe "/home/hb/.lyxpipe"
\user_name ""
\user_email ""
\preview_scale_factor 0.8

#
# SCREEN & FONTS SECTION ############################
#

\screen_zoom 130
\screen_font_roman "Abyssinica SIL"
\screen_font_sans "Abyssinica SIL"
\screen_font_typewriter "Courier"
\screen_font_sizes 5 7 8 9 10 12 14.4 17.260000000000002 20.739999999999998 24.879999999999999
\fullscreen_limit true
\fullscreen_width 850
\single_instance false
\forward_search_dvi "okular --unique \"file:$$o#src:$$n $$f\""
\forward_search_pdf "okular --unique \"file:$$o#src:$$n $$f\""

#
# COLOR SECTION ###################################
#

# solarized dark
\set_color "cursor" "#839496"
\set_color "background" "#002b36"
\set_color "foreground" "#839496"
\set_color "selection" "#586e75"
\set_color "selectiontext" "#002b36"
\set_color "latex" "#839496"
\set_color "preview" "#839496"
\set_color "inlinecompletion" "#586e75"
\set_color "nonuniqueinlinecompletion" "#586e75"
\set_color "note" "#268bd2"
\set_color "notebg" "#073642"
\set_color "commentbg" "#073642"
\set_color "greyedoutbg" "#073642"
\set_color "shaded" "#dc322f"
\set_color "listingsbg" "#268bd2"
\set_color "footlabel" "#6c71c4"
\set_color "urllabel" "#839496"
\set_color "urltext" "#839496"
\set_color "depthbar" "#2aa198"
\set_color "language" "#839496"
\set_color "command" "#2aa198"
\set_color "commandbg" "#073642"
\set_color "commandframe" "#586e75"
\set_color "special" "#81a2be"
\set_color "graphicsbg" "#073642"
\set_color "math" "#839496"
\set_color "mathbg" "#002b36"
\set_color "mathmacrobg" "#073642"
\set_color "mathmacroframe" "#073642"
\set_color "mathmacroblend" "#839496"
\set_color "mathmacronewarg" "#839496"
\set_color "mathframe" "#839496"
\set_color "mathcorners" "#073642"
\set_color "mathline" "#839496"
\set_color "collapsable" "#d0caff"
\set_color "collapsableframe" "#073642"
\set_color "insetframe" "#586e75"
\set_color "eolmarker" "#2aa198"
\set_color "added_space" "#2aa198"
\set_color "appendix" "#dc322f"
\set_color "changebar" "#4d4d4c"
\set_color "addedtext" "#8b0000"
\set_color "changedtextauthor1" "#2aa198"
\set_color "changedtextauthor2" "#d33682"
\set_color "changedtextauthor3" "#cf4b16"
\set_color "changedtextauthor4" "#b58900"
\set_color "changedtextauthor5" "#859900"
\set_color "tabularline" "#839496"
\set_color "tabularonoffline" "#586e75"
\set_color "newpage" "#2aa198"
\set_color "pagebreak" "#268bd2"
\set_color "buttonframe" "#586e75"
\set_color "buttonbg" "#002b36"
\set_color "buttonhoverbg" "#073642"
\set_color "paragraphmarker" "#8abeb7"
\set_color "previewframe" "#839496"

#
# PRINTER SECTION ###################################
#


#
# TEX SECTION #######################################
#


#
# FILE SECTION ######################################
#


#
# PLAIN TEXT EXPORT SECTION ##############################
#


#
# SPELLCHECKER SECTION ##############################
#


#
# LANGUAGE SUPPORT SECTION ##########################
#

\spellchecker enchant
\spellcheck_continuously true

#
# 2nd MISC SUPPORT SECTION ##########################
#


#
# FORMATS SECTION ##########################
#

\format "bmp" "bmp" "BMP" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "dia" "dia" "DIA" "" "auto" "auto" "vector"
\format "dvi" "dvi" "DVI" "D" "okular" "" "document,vector,menu=export"
\format "excel" "xls" "Excel spreadsheet" "" "" "auto" "document"
\format "fen" "fen" "FEN" "" "auto" "auto" ""
\format "fig" "fig" "FIG" "" "auto" "auto" "vector"
\format "gif" "gif" "GIF" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "gnumeric" "gnumeric" "Gnumeric spreadsheet" "" "" "auto" "document"
\format "agr" "agr" "Grace" "" "auto" "auto" "vector"
\format "jpg" "jpg" "JPEG" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "noteedit" "not" "Noteedit" "" "auto" "auto" "vector"
\format "oocalc" "ods" "OpenOffice spreadsheet" "" "" "auto" "document"
\format "pbm" "pbm" "PBM" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "pgm" "pgm" "PGM" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "png" "png" "PNG" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "ppm" "ppm" "PPM" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "tiff" "tif" "TIFF" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "tgif" "obj" "Tgif" "" "auto" "auto" "vector"
\format "xbm" "xbm" "XBM" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""
\format "xpm" "xpm" "XPM" "" "xdg-open" "auto" ""

#
# CONVERTERS SECTION ##########################
#


#
# COPIERS SECTION ##########################
#
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete preferences file with the change? Also, what LyX version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lyx v 2.0.8.1
I will post the preference file as I currently use it, but if I change something from within Lyx no changes seem to be made to the `preferences`

Comment: I just tested and it works well for me. I'm not sure what the problem is. In the preferences dialog you are clicking on "save" and not "apply", right?

Comment: Dude, I hate to say, it but I just checked and clicking save actually did the trick....  Thank you though! :)
Would you care to post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: in preferences use the "save" button to permanently save, not the "apply" button.

You've run into a common confusion, represented by [this](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10016) LyX bug. The "apply" button is meant only to apply it for that LyX session. It is a useful feature if you understand the difference, because this way you can experiment with various preferences without concern that you will permanently change something (and forget how to get back to what is was before). Although it is a useful feature, it has caused confusion to many users (including myself).